# How to indicate that one role-playing date dimension is the "primary" (much more popular) date?

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

Many fact tables in our relational data warehouse will have a "primary" date as well as other dates.  How should I indicate this prioritization in the data model so that applications built on top of the data model will guide users toward the "primary" date by default?

For example, in the Sales fact table, there's a "Sale Date" column that is the primary date, but also a "Recording Date" that's seldom used in reporting.

Another example: the WarehouseReceiving fact table has a "Delivery Date" column that is primary, but also a "Transaction Entry Date" which is rarely used.

Is there a convention for how to model one role as more important than the others when there are [role-playing dimensions](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/role-playing-dimension/)?

Or is trying to define a primary role a bad idea because it will confuse users in the case where there's not a natural "primary" role?

Our platform is SQL Server 2014 if that matters, but the question is intended to be platform-neutral.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "primary" concept in role playing dimensions.

Each dimension and role is there for a business reason. In your case sale_date and delivery_date look important, but perhaps you want to question the role of recording_date and transaction_entry_date, as they may not play any part in a business process.

Let's assume that we only have sale_date and delivery_date. Which is more important? Neither. Both. It depends on the perspective of the person writing the query.

When dealing with fact tables containing multiple dates, one technique I use is to order date columns by their usual sequence in the business process. For example, date_ordered comes before date_shipped, which comes before date_invoiced and date_paid. Keeping the date columns together, and sequenced, may help to familiarise a casual BI user with the data.

Comment: Apologies for repeating some of your points - I wrote most of my post up earlier but didn't have a chance to post it. Hopefully both answers will offer something to the OP and to other readers, though.

Answer (score 0):

As long as all of the dates are clearly named or otherwise identified for your users, I don't see why you would need to do this. Stepping away from your technical mindset on this for a moment, if you look at this from the perspective of an end user, are they going to think "this same type of field is listed more than once, so now I don't know which is the main one"? I suspect they'll think something more like "I need to look at sales amounts by the day the sales happened... oh, Sale Date sounds like what I'm looking for." If you have cases where names really could be unclear then you might need to take further steps - whether that's renaming them in agreement with your users, carrying out training, or setting up documentation.

You really need your users to understand the meaning of all Dimensions without needing to use their Fact table context, anyway. Say you put this into an SSAS cube; the Dimensions will show up independently and might cut across multiple Fact tables, so anything saying one is the primary date might be true for one Fact and not for another. And you might have cases where one user is mostly interested in analyzing data by Sale Date, but another is mostly interested in analyzing it by Recording Date. Which is the primary date in that case?

If you're concerned that you don't have a good way to communicate the meaning of your data fields to your users, consider setting up a data dictionary. I'll not link to a specific tutorial as I haven't verified any and there seem to be different ways to do it, but if you search for *data dictionary SSAS* on Google you'll find numerous suggestions for setting up descriptions on your cube fields, and then displaying this information in an SSRS report. If you're not using SSAS cubes as the main way people access the data then you might need to do something a bit different, but hopefully this gives you an idea for a suitable solution.

Depending on how you're disseminating the data, you could also look at trimming down which fields are available to which people - for instance, by what permissions they have in SQL Server if they're using Report Builder, or using SSAS perspectives if they use a cube. I wouldn't do this unless your users are complaining that they are finding the number of available Dimensions problematic in some way though - sometimes if there are a lot of irrelevant fields it can be irritating and slow people down (and yes, could lead to people choosing the wrong field in some cases), but you don't want to risk hiding relevant data.